# Can I increase the amount of time before I'm asked to force quit an app?

Tags: release-freya, applications

I've noticed that some of my newer games will cause that dialogue box to pop-up during their initial loading screens. It seems like if it takes more than 5 or 10 seconds to load a game, the OS freaks out and thinks it's hung.

Is there a way to increase the amount of time before the OS decides a process might need to be forceably terminated?

Comment: Essentially, I believe the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The value is hard coded in LibMutter, the programming library behind the window manager in elementary OS.

Even while loading, an application should remain responsive to the window manager. The application becoming non-responsive will trigger this dialog. This is by design. The window manager is behaving properly. You should file a bug report against software that becomes non-responsive to prevent this behavior in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: You know, re-reading my question, I didn't explain it completely. Elementary OS says "this program has become unresponsive" but if I just hit "cancel" and flip back over to the game I'm loading, it runs fine. Elementary OS apparently believes the game to be hung when in fact it isn't.